how to convert unix epoch with nanosecond precision to timestamp?
I have data from an external DB source in a BQ table. The data type in that external DB datetime columns (I think SQL Server) has the following schema information:

length: 8
scale: 3
precision: 23

The datetime columns are saved as INTEGER in BigQuery.
Some real values for example:



CREATETIME
CHANGETIME




1380308645543333333
1416903877310000000


1416907372976666666
1458294273450000000


1363698020000000000
1406901312793333333


1717156474010000000
1717156490623333333



I need to convert this data to a timestamp column in BQ but BQ does not seem to support a conversion from unix epoch time with nanoseconds to a timestamp?
Highest precision I could find in the documentation (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions) is TIMESTAMP_MICROS but there seems to be no TIMESTAMP_NANOS?
And if I can't convert unix epoch with nanoseconds to a timestamp what is the best way to convert it to a timestamp with second precision when I don't need such a high precision?

Why not just divide by 1000000000 and convert from seconds?

As pointed out by @dan04 you can divide by 1000000000 and convert from seconds as follows:
SELECT
  TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(CAST(CREATETIME / 1000000000 AS INT64)) AS CREATETIME_TIMESTAMP,
  TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(CAST(CHANGETIME / 1000000000 AS INT64)) AS CHANGETIME_TIMESTAMP
FROM `dataset_id.table_name`;

